# Singleton collections in Directus

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, directus

I am using **Directus** (v9) with **Nuxt 3**. I managed to display on the frontend a page with a blog feed like **my-site.com/my-blog** . And pages with individual posts, like **my-site.com/my-blog/1** , **my-site.com/my-blog/2**  etc.

But in Directus it is possible to create collections as a single object or **singleton**. I need this in order to create pages like **my-site.com/about-us** , **my-site.com/contacts** etc. But I can't output these pages to Nuxt 3 yet. I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved by the use of such a design:

```
<script setup>
const { getSingletonItem } = useDirectusItems();
const route = useRoute();
const post = await getSingletonItem({ collection: "my-collection" });
</script>
```